# Read divert sockets in java?

Tags: java, ftp, tcp, ipfw

If I was to create a ipfw divert rule to forward all FTP traffic to a specific socket, is it possible to use Java to connect to the socekt and read the packet information? If so, how would i go about reading/writing to the scoket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean. If you're using a divert rule, then all you have to do is listen on that ip:port combination in your java app and you're all set. If you want to read the actual destination endpoint information, you'll need to use JNI for that.

Comment: That's not true. [When you create the socket, you actually need to specify it's a divert port](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/4/divert/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's like a normal socket, you can read/write from/to it, but on Mac OS X, if you do want to modify the packet and insert it back, you need to recalculate the tcp check sum first.

http://blog.loudhush.ro/2006/08/using-divert-sockets-on-mac-os-x.html

This is a good post that introduce the basic usage of the divert socket on Mac OS X. You can actually create the rule in your C code.

For you case, just scan the packet for TCP or IP header and parse for whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't natively support binding onto a Divert socket. It's not exactly a cross-platform feature (it's a BSD/Mac OS X) thing...

You could try using the "socket" native function call through JNA.

Your code will look something like this:

```
public interface LibC extends Library {
  int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
  int close(int fd);

  /* stuff from /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers ... */
  /* ... /sys/socket.h */ 
  static int AF_INET = 2;
  static int SOCK_RAW = 3;
  /* .. netinet/in.h */
  static int IPPROTO_DIVERT = 254;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  LibC lib = (LibC) Native.loadLibrary("C", LibC.class);
  int fd = lib.socket(LibC.AF_INET, LibC.SOCK_RAW, LibC.IPPROTO_DIVERT);
  if (fd <= 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("couldn't open divert socket. am I root?");
  }
  System.out.println(fd);
  System.out.println(lib.close(fd));
}
```